# PHP: Find element with certain property value in array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I can't think of it right now. Is there an array function or something that lets me search through an array and find the item that has a certain property value? For example:

```
$people = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'Alice',
    'age' => 25,
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Waldo',
    'age' => 89,
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Bob',
    'age' => 27,
  ),
);
```

How can I find and get Waldo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following snippet you have a general idea how to do it:

```
foreach ($people as $i => $person)
{
    if (array_key_exists('name', $person) && $person['name'] == 'Waldo')
        echo('Waldo found at ' . $i);
}
```

Then you can make the previous snippet as a general use function like:

```
function SearchArray($array, $searchIndex, $searchValue)
{
    if (!is_array($array) || $searchIndex == '')
        return false;

    foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    {
        if (is_array($v) && array_key_exists($searchIndex, $v) && $v[$searchIndex] == $searchValue)
            return $k;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$foundIndex = SearchArray($people, 'name', 'Waldo'); //Search by name
$foundIndex = SearchArray($people, 'age', 89); //Search by age
```

But watch out as the function can return 0 and false which both evaluates to false (use something like *if ($foundIndex !== false)* or *if ($foundIndex === false)*).

Comment: Nice function. Think I would declare the function as  `function SearchArray(array $array, ...` and skip the `is_array` check though =)

Comment: I know there is no other option, but still stupid that you really need to loop though the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findByName($array, $name) {
    foreach ($array as $person) {
        if ($person['name'] == $name) {
            return $person;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCustomSearch($key) {
   foreach($people as $p) {
      if($p['name']==$searchKey) return $p
   }
}

getCustomSearch('waldo');
```